# Accessing private variables through levels of classes.

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation

So in my current understanding of how to use encapsulation correctly it is a good rule of thumb to make variables private and access them through member functions of the class like this:

```
class Aclass{
private:
    int avar;
public:
    void ch_avar(int val){avar = val};
    int get_avar() {return avar;}
};
```

My question is how would I access a private member of a class instance which is its self a private member of another class.  Here is an example of the way I have been trying to do it (not retyping the example above for brevity)

```
class LargerClass{
private:
    int other_var;
    Aclass A; //has two instances of class "Aclass" 
    Aclass B; 
public: 
    void ch_other_var(int val){other_var = val;}
    int get_other_var() {return other_var;}

     // this is the important line for the question
    int get_avar(Aclass X){return X.get_avar();} 
};
```

Now In my real program there are a few more levels of this and I keep getting the compilation error that "Aclass" is an unknown type. Even though I have included the header file for Aclass in the Larger class.  Since I am stuck I thought It would be good to find out if this is even the correct (or an acceptable way) of doing what I want.  I am new to OOP and this feels sloppy to me.

Comment: The correct question to ask is not "how", but "why". The answer to that question will likely reveal either an issue with your design, or with your understanding of OO principles.

Comment: Actually the "good rule of thumb" is to make variables private *and not access them at all from outside the class itself*. That's why they are called "private". If you are handling a class' variables through getters and setters, you want a struct, not a class. A class "does things", it doesn't provide access to its innards for *you* to "do things" with them. That's encapsulation -- you send a message to a class to "do something", and what that means with regards to the class variables is none of your concern.

Comment: An error like _"Aclass" is an unknown type_" is nothing to do with members being private, you need to fix that first, it has nothing to do with encapsulation

Comment: To be honest the setter are there just out of habit from what I learned in the compsci 101 class I took a ew years ago (my only classroom programing experience).  In reality my main function uses the getter's to print information... and now that I say that out loud the function should be print_var not get_var ..womp thank you for the help everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the private member of a class instance which is its self a private member of another class, can be done this way. You don't need to pass a Aclass X. It is unneccessary. You can call it by the instance name you have given..

```
class LargerClass{
private:
    int other_var;
    Aclass A; //has two instances of class "Aclass" 
    Aclass B; 
public: 
    void ch_other_var(int val){other_var = val;}
    int get_other_var() {return other_var;}

     // this is the important line for the question
    int get_avar_A(){return A.get_avar();} 
};
```

If you have 20 instances of Aclass, rather you create a vector of Aclass instances.

```
class LargerClass{
private:
    int other_var;
    Aclass A[20]; 
public: 
    void ch_other_var(int val){other_var = val;}
    int get_other_var() {return other_var;}

     // this is the important line for the question
    int[] get_avar_A()
   {
     int other_var[20];
     for(int i= 0; i<20; i++)
     {
       other_var[i] = A[i].get_avar();
     }
     return other_var;
    } 
};
```

Comment: I see but in this case wouldn't I need different functions for A and B? my goal was to make the function work for both

Comment: How could you make it work for both? the caller can't say `x.get_avar(x.A)` because `x.A` is private

Comment: See in my actual project I have about 20 instances instead of two I think I need rethink my approach to this project thank you for your help though.

Comment: if you have 20 instances, create a vector/array of the instances.. rather than putting each of them as a private variable..